# is There an oracle error code to raise when I finish a plsql block without close an explicit cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, cursor

I'm coding a lot of PL/SQL blocks using explicit cursors to fill some tables... So I need a "reminder" to close all cursors. So... Is there an Oracle error code to raise when I finish a plsql block without close an explicit cursor? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. However cursors in anonymous block are automatically closed when the blocks finish. You should explicitly close the cursors though, as it is considered good practice.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and your help. I appreciate your help so much!